# MongoDB How to query data in object with random names?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `'news'` in database as follows.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a6d068b0088c92a34324d8e"),
"4210003170944" : 
    {
    "date" : "20180126",
    "sectionId" : "100",
    "rank" : "1",
    "newsTitle" : "Foo",
    "oid" : "421",
    "aid" : "0003170944"
    },
"2140000800903" : 
    {
    "date" : "20180126",
    "sectionId" : "100",
    "rank" : "2",
    "newsTitle" : "Bar",
    "oid" : "214",
    "aid" : "0000800903"
    }
}
```

If I want to search all news with `"oid" : "421"`, what command should I use?

I've tried

```
db.locations.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d068b0088c92a34324d8e")}, { oid : '421' })
```

but it doesn't fetch me anything.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Because your field names are not same you cannot do this. `db.news.find( { '2140000800903.oid' : "214" } )` will work but does not satisfy what you are asking. Read [Searching for value of any field in MongoDB without explicitly naming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790819/searching-for-value-of-any-field-in-mongodb-without-explicitly-naming-it) which has some work around for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to search all news with "oid" : "421", what command should I
>   use?

As per MongoDB BOL [$match (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

The $match stage has the following prototype form:

```
{ $match: { <query> } }
```

So, in your case the query will be like that

```
   db.locations.aggregate({$match: {'4210003170944.oid': '421'}}).pretty()
```

Let's from starting onward i am going to show through `mongo shell` .
First i am going to create a **collection name** as `locations`. which is a collection name in your query. Then i will insert the data , which you have provided through the code and the do the desire query with `$match (aggregation)`.

```
> db.createCollection("locations")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.locations.insert({
... "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d068b0088c92a34324d8e"),
... "4210003170944" :
...     {
...     "date" : "20180126",
...     "sectionId" : "100",
...     "rank" : "1",
...     "newsTitle" : "Foo",
...     "oid" : "421",
...     "aid" : "0003170944"
...     },
... "2140000800903" :
...     {
...     "date" : "20180126",
...     "sectionId" : "100",
...     "rank" : "2",
...     "newsTitle" : "Bar",
...     "oid" : "214",
...     "aid" : "0000800903"
...     }
... }
... )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
> db.locations.aggregate({$match: {'4210003170944.oid': '421'}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d068b0088c92a34324d8e"),
        "4210003170944" : {
                "date" : "20180126",
                "sectionId" : "100",
                "rank" : "1",
                "newsTitle" : "Foo",
                "oid" : "421",
                "aid" : "0003170944"
        },
        "2140000800903" : {
                "date" : "20180126",
                "sectionId" : "100",
                "rank" : "2",
                "newsTitle" : "Bar",
                "oid" : "214",
                "aid" : "0000800903"
        }
}
```

Hope this will help out to you.