# Mongodb Sort Array Objects within Array using expression

Tags: mongodb, query, array, sorting

Please help to make query in mongodb.
I want mongo query in which sort array objects using some expression.
Example.
I have documents like

```
                {
                "_id:"5e0846c922427bdc824d3943",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "kevin"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "patel"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "surat"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Boy"

            },
            {
                "_id":"5e08471d6053718c808cbab8",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                     {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "alice"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "somani"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "bharuch"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Boy"

            },
            {
                "_id":"5e0847392b8622f8100267e3",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                     {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "Isha"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "Trivedi"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "Mumbai"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Girl"

            }
```

and when pass filter parameter on custom_field_id = "fname"
then it will display results in following ascending or descending way.

```
                {
                "_id":"5e08471d6053718c808cbab8",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                     {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "alice"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "somani"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "bharuch"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Boy",

            },{
                "_id":"5e0847392b8622f8100267e3",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                     {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "Isha"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "Trivedi"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "Mumbai"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Girl",

            },
            {
                "_id:"5e0846c922427bdc824d3943",
                "isActive" : true,
                "customFieldArray" : [
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "fname",
                        "field_value" : "kevin"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "lname",
                        "field_value" : "patel"
                    },
                    {
                        "custom_field_id" : "city",
                        "field_value" : "surat"
                    }
                ],
                "creationMode" : "adminForm",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-21T06:40:20.033Z"),
                "gender" : "Boy"

            }
```

Comment: What is the MongoDB Version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan MongoDB version 3.6

Comment: Does your example represent three documents or a single document with three documents embedded? It would be helpful to include top-level `_id`s for clarity on the document structure.

Comment: @Stennie Question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation sorts the *documents* based on the inputs INPUT_EXPRESSION and SORT_ORDER. The input expression is matched with the `customFieldArray`'s `custom_field_id` value *and* the documents are sorted based on the corresponding `field_value`.

```
var INPUT_EXPRESSION = "fname";    // values can be "fname", "city" or "lname" 
var SORT_ORDER = 1;    // values can be 1 (ascending) or -1 (descending)

db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          customFieldTemp: {
              $filter: {
                   input: "$customFieldArray",
                      as: "arr",
                    cond: {
                             $eq: [ "$$arr.custom_field_id", INPUT_EXPRESSION ]
                    }
              }
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          customFieldTemp: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$customFieldTemp", 0 ] }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { "customFieldTemp.field_value" : SORT_ORDER } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { customFieldTemp: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

*Example*:

From the sample input documents in the question post, if the INPUT_EXPRESSION = "city" *and* SORT_ORDER = 1, the documents are sorted as:  `_id: "5e08471d6053718c808cbab8"` ("bharuch"), `_id: "5e0847392b8622f8100267e3"` ("mumbai") and `_id: "5e0846c922427bdc824d3943"` ("surat").

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) The [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) condition.

For example

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({$match: {'customFieldArray.custom_field_id' : 'lname'}})
```

For further your ref [MongoDB find() not getting anything](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196442/mongodb-find-not-getting-anything/196446#196446), [MongoDB How to query data in object with random names?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196426/mongodb-how-to-query-data-in-object-with-random-names/196435#196435)

Comment: Thanks but here I need sorting based on `customFieldArray.custom_field_id` value. If I pass `customFieldArray.custom_field_id : lname` then `customFieldArray.field_value`  it's values will be sorted.

Comment: @5a01d01P, As you have already said that you want to filter that's why i have been written the syntax according to your query desire. Now you want to sort according to your desire field value _customFieldArray.custom_field_id_ . Right

Comment: Yes, I need sorting but it's not like normal sorting. please go through my question I explained in detail, how results will be fetched on the filter and sorted.